# Hibernate - Unable to make JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/hibernatedb

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to create a basic hibernate application using hibernate 5.2.10 release. When I run it it says

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to make JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/hibernatedb]
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/hibernatedb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">udpate</property>
    <mapping class="com.chandu.app.model.UserDetails"/>
</session-factory>
```

Main class:

```
public class HibernateTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    UserDetails user = getUserObject();
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.clear();
}

private static UserDetails getUserObject() {
    UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
    user.setUserName("Test User");

    return user;
}
```

Console:

[image: Console Output]

Code Structure:

[image]

I have gone through some of the forums, but couldnt find a solution for the same.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Add a colon after mysql in your connection URL.

Comment: @duffymo Hey thanks. It got worked.

Comment: Glad to help.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/hibernatedb`

Use a colon (`:`) both before and after "mysql":

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb`