# Java Hibernate MySql "Unable to make JDBC Connection"

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

For a long while I'm trying to connect hibernate and mysql.

It's not problem with database or Intellij 'cause I can with no problem add db as datasource  and create|drop tables or insert values into via Intellij sql terminal after connection established.
But after using `SessionFactory` I get "Unable to make JDBC Connection" error.

Using `DriverManager.getConnection` works but it's not using hibernate and I would have to write queries and I would avoid that.

I'm using Hibernate 5.3.7

Edit: fixed quote mark in url, but didn't help

Edit2: So I did some digging(debugging) and I found that error occurs in line of "DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java" in line which says"connections.add(connectionCreator.createConnection()". It's implementation is BasicConnectionCreator class which field

```
final Connection conn = makeConnection( url, connectionProps );
```

which is always null and it throws exception, but when I debug this the parameters are fine.

Edit3: I tried to use previous version of Hibernate, MySql Server and Sql Connector/J. I'm just wondering how trivial is the mistake that I'm making.

`hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospital</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pwd</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
</session-factory>
```

`HibernateUtil.java`

```
package com.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {

  private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

  private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("\n\nInitial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);             
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
  }

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        // loads configuration and mappings
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry
                = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

        // builds a session factory from the service registry
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    }
    return sessionFactory;
  }

  public static void shutdown() {
    // Close caches and connection pools
    getSessionFactory().close();
  }

}
```

Error code:

```
** Exception in SessionFactory **
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to make JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospital]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:77)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
at com.util.HibernateUtil.configureSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:29)
at com.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:40)
at com.Main.main(Main.java:95)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.Main.main(Main.java:96)
```

Comment: could you please provide the version of hibernate you're using?

Comment: I would also invite you to take care of making the question readable by using proper paragraphs, and correctly indent the code.  
That would help the readers a lot, which in turn would make it easier to get an answer.
And btw, nobody is really interested in how important your project is, people give their help here pro bono, so please try to phrase the question professionally and you'll be answered accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to make JDBC Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27011410/5221149): *After Mysql 5.x use `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` class*

Comment: Remove the `"` at the beginning of the `jdbc:` url. Problem noticed after reading [Hibernate - Unable to make JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/hibernatedb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891989/hibernate-unable-to-make-jdbc-connection-jdbcmysql-localhost3306-hibernate#comment74817878_43891989), i.e. with a little **research** of articles with same error.

Comment: @pagoda_5b It's 5.3.7, sorry I missed it, it is mentioned now. Also removed unnecessary comments like "i need it fast". Sorry was writing in rush.

Comment: @Andreas Properties with username password and dialect are in file. Removes " added : and it didn't help but thanks for feedback.

Comment: Added `:`? Where? There was no missing colon. Update question to remove errors you've already fixed, so we can see what is left to fix, e.g. did you change the dialect?

Comment: @Andreas, you mentioned post with guy whose problem was missing colon. I've tried every dialect, I found, used 4 different methods of SessionFactory, I put hibernate config file in every place in project it can be. I tried also runing on a clean system to check if some trash of earlier attempts with db's don't obstruct. So I'm trying to fix it for more than 3 days so I checked many ways, but every idea is possibly good idea.

Comment: As Andreas said, remove the `"` in front of your JDBC url, and if that did not help, then **edit** your question with the new situation and the error you get now.